# Not able to add remote ice candidate in webrtc

Tags: javascript, web, webrtc

I am trying to establish a p2p audio/video connection b/w 2 peers. Peer P1 sends an offer to peer P2. On getting offer, P2 does-

```
{
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(ice);
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg.offer),
            onSetRemoteDescriptionSuccess, onSetSessionDescriptionError);                    

    function onSetRemoteDescriptionSuccess() {
        console.log('onSetRemoteDescriptionSuccess called');                                 
    }                                                                                        

    function onSetSessionDescriptionError() {
        console.log('onSetSessionDescriptionError called');                                  
    }                                                                                        

    pc.onicecandidate = function(evt) {                                                      
        if (evt.candidate) {
            console.log('got local icecandidate', evt.candidate);                            
            send_ice_candicate(evt.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,                                  
                      evt.candidate.sdpMid,
                      evt.candidate.candidate                                                
                      );                                                                     
        }                                                                                    
    }                                                                                        

    pc.onaddstream = function (evt) {
        var remote_video = document.getElementById('remote_video');                          
        remote_video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(evt.stream);                           
    }                                                                                        

    navigator.getUserMedia({ "audio": true, "video": true },                                 
            gotStream, logError);
} 

function gotStream(stream) {                                                                     
    pc.addStream(stream);                                                                        

    var local_video = document.getElementById('local_video');                                    
    local_video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);                                        

    pc.createAnswer(function(answer) {
        pc.setLocalDescription(answer);
        console.log('creating answer', answer.sdp)                                           
        signalingChannel.send(answer.sdp);                                                 
        });
    got_ice_candidate(remote_ice_candidate);                                                     
}
```

remote_ice_candidate is something which was received before offer and hence is buffered and I am trying to add after the answer is ready and other pre-requisites are done.

But still I am getting error while trying to add remote ice candidate.

Peer connection object on P2 looks like-

```
RTCPeerConnection {ondatachannel: null, oniceconnectionstatechange: null, onremovestream: null, onaddstream: function, onsignalingstatechange: null…}
iceConnectionState: "new"
iceGatheringState: "gathering"
localDescription: RTCSessionDescription
sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 5043546633484176483 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s=-
↵t=0 0
↵a=group:BUNDLE audio video
↵a=msid-semantic: WMS irIWtGZ87WFi8P6XH94I85sUsKYcu775glZk
↵m=audio 10990 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 106 105 13 126
↵c=IN IP4 122.171.69.180
↵a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=candidate:3022624816 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.4 50063 typ host generation 0
↵a=candidate:4205470912 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.4 0 typ host generation 0
↵a=candidate:494278629 1 udp 1686052607 122.171.69.180 10990 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.4 rport 50063 generation 0
↵a=ice-ufrag:1ZCyumc5I0T8mbFJ
↵a=ice-pwd:+JUisFsiKa8ezPXDIuzu99tv
↵a=fingerprint:sha-256 BE:16:E6:7B:C8:18:E6:B9:50:D9:31:F3:24:85:3B:63:26:BA:EA:6B:5D:F4:4E:0E:29:47:16:C0:1D:9D:B7:F3
↵a=setup:active
↵a=mid:audio
↵a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
↵a=sendrecv
↵a=rtcp-mux
↵a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
↵a=fmtp:111 minptime=10
↵a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
↵a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
↵a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
↵a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
↵a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
↵a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
↵a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
↵a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
↵a=maxptime:60
↵a=ssrc:2173896727 cname:PZV2reyyZuw6KufJ
↵a=ssrc:2173896727 msid:irIWtGZ87WFi8P6XH94I85sUsKYcu775glZk fb1b496d-ffa9-43cd-940a-7c68df86d3b3
↵a=ssrc:2173896727 mslabel:irIWtGZ87WFi8P6XH94I85sUsKYcu775glZk
↵a=ssrc:2173896727 label:fb1b496d-ffa9-43cd-940a-7c68df86d3b3
↵m=video 10990 RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117
↵c=IN IP4 122.171.69.180
↵a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=candidate:3022624816 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.4 50063 typ host generation 0
↵a=candidate:4205470912 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.4 0 typ host generation 0
↵a=candidate:494278629 1 udp 1686052607 122.171.69.180 10990 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.4 rport 50063 generation 0
↵a=ice-ufrag:1ZCyumc5I0T8mbFJ
↵a=ice-pwd:+JUisFsiKa8ezPXDIuzu99tv
↵a=fingerprint:sha-256 BE:16:E6:7B:C8:18:E6:B9:50:D9:31:F3:24:85:3B:63:26:BA:EA:6B:5D:F4:4E:0E:29:47:16:C0:1D:9D:B7:F3
↵a=setup:active
↵a=mid:video
↵a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
↵a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
↵a=sendrecv
↵a=rtcp-mux
↵a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
↵a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
↵a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
↵a=ssrc:2118221653 cname:PZV2reyyZuw6KufJ
↵a=ssrc:2118221653 msid:irIWtGZ87WFi8P6XH94I85sUsKYcu775glZk a735b317-1752-40fa-96df-511c0febb55e
↵a=ssrc:2118221653 mslabel:irIWtGZ87WFi8P6XH94I85sUsKYcu775glZk
↵a=ssrc:2118221653 label:a735b317-1752-40fa-96df-511c0febb55e
↵"
type: "answer"
__proto__: RTCSessionDescription
onaddstream: function (evt) {
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
ondatachannel: null
onicecandidate: function (evt) {
oniceconnectionstatechange: null
onnegotiationneeded: null
onremovestream: null
onsignalingstatechange: null
remoteDescription: RTCSessionDescription
sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 8847796014807563532 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s=-
↵t=0 0
↵a=group:BUNDLE audio video
↵a=msid-semantic: WMS na7tuNpnYZpmg56IJULDdF8oMUG8V5ndTjkK
↵m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 106 105 13 126
↵c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=ice-ufrag:mfL29tarMKRBN9F/
↵a=ice-pwd:/my1DZo1Yjne4BrcQGKN1o3I
↵a=ice-options:google-ice
↵a=fingerprint:sha-256 BE:16:E6:7B:C8:18:E6:B9:50:D9:31:F3:24:85:3B:63:26:BA:EA:6B:5D:F4:4E:0E:29:47:16:C0:1D:9D:B7:F3
↵a=setup:actpass
↵a=mid:audio
↵a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
↵a=sendrecv
↵a=rtcp-mux
↵a=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:ggGTdSmkygu0aVidv2M6kO25w5DX/OknOXFnRBYK
↵a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
↵a=fmtp:111 minptime=10
↵a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
↵a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
↵a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
↵a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
↵a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
↵a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
↵a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
↵a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
↵a=maxptime:60
↵a=ssrc:702054304 cname:++QJWJ3eyXhSOSgH
↵a=ssrc:702054304 msid:na7tuNpnYZpmg56IJULDdF8oMUG8V5ndTjkK 054d6450-034f-48ca-85dc-3a843c7f7554
↵a=ssrc:702054304 mslabel:na7tuNpnYZpmg56IJULDdF8oMUG8V5ndTjkK
↵a=ssrc:702054304 label:054d6450-034f-48ca-85dc-3a843c7f7554
↵m=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117
↵c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=ice-ufrag:mfL29tarMKRBN9F/
↵a=ice-pwd:/my1DZo1Yjne4BrcQGKN1o3I
↵a=ice-options:google-ice
↵a=fingerprint:sha-256 BE:16:E6:7B:C8:18:E6:B9:50:D9:31:F3:24:85:3B:63:26:BA:EA:6B:5D:F4:4E:0E:29:47:16:C0:1D:9D:B7:F3
↵a=setup:actpass
↵a=mid:video
↵a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
↵a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
↵a=sendrecv
↵a=rtcp-mux
↵a=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:ggGTdSmkygu0aVidv2M6kO25w5DX/OknOXFnRBYK
↵a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
↵a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
↵a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
↵a=ssrc:846853801 cname:++QJWJ3eyXhSOSgH
↵a=ssrc:846853801 msid:na7tuNpnYZpmg56IJULDdF8oMUG8V5ndTjkK c0dde33c-f422-4774-9f7b-65cec136e107
↵a=ssrc:846853801 mslabel:na7tuNpnYZpmg56IJULDdF8oMUG8V5ndTjkK
↵a=ssrc:846853801 label:c0dde33c-f422-4774-9f7b-65cec136e107
↵"
type: "offer"
__proto__: RTCSessionDescription
signalingState: "stable"
__proto__: RTCPeerConnection
```

The error that I get is

```
Failed to add Ice Candidate: Error processing ICE candidate
```

Comment: could you include the code that you are using to add the Ice Candidate? Is it an array of candidates you are trying to add? Could you include the printout of the object you are trying to add as a candidate? Is this in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: In my case , error was same , but this error was occurring due to "Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_SENTOFFER".
Problem was in my code , offer was being created from both the side.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know exactly from where you have remote_ice_candidate object. But to deal proper with ice messages you should have something like this:

First:
On ice candidate event you should send it to other peer. e.g.:

```
pc.onicecandidate = function (event) {
    if (!event || !event.candidate) return;
    socket.emit("iceCandidate", event.candidate); //send ice candidate through your signaling server to other peer
};
```

Then:
We should also listen on "iceCandidate" message from signaling server and add ice candidate to RTCPeerConnection e.g. :

```
socket.on("iceCandidate", function(iceCandidate){
  pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(iceCandidate));
});
```

And that's all.
From my observation, exchanging ice messages starts after offer/answer communication, so until then you should not have ice candidate object ready.
Of course this code work only in chrome.

Comment: liosedhel is correct, ICE messages should come after the Offer-Answer exchange. Also the candidates do not need to be in the SDP's, your time is better spent implementing trickle-ice.

Comment: ICE candidates start gathering after setting local description `setLocalDescription()`, which could be irrespective of  Offer-Answer exchange. Candidates will be generated even before receiving the answer

Comment: @UnahD so what to do then, if candidates start getting generated even though you still havent set remotesdp, do i get it right remotesdp should be set before addIceCandidate() call

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Yes (_remote description should be set before addIceCandidate() call_). Such synchronization has to be done in client side

Comment: i see, so what's a good strategy to not send or add ICE candidates until remoteDescription is set. One way I think of is to create offer, dont set localDescription, wait for answer, when get an answer set local and remote description together.

Comment: should i listen to each  new RTCPeerConnection(x) like so 
p1.onicecandidate = (event) => {
    
      };
p2.onicecandidate = (event) => {
    
      };

Answer (score 3):

This is a reply to comments asking how to ensure ice candidates are only added after the remote description is set:

```
let candidates = [];
let remoteDescriptionSet = false;

function wsMessage(ev) {
  if (!ev || !ev.data) return;
  const json = JSON.parse(ev.data);
  if (!json) return;
  if (json.type === 'answer') {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(json)
    .then(() => {
      remoteDescriptionSet = true;
      console.log('remote description set');
      return Promise.all(candidates.map(c => pc.addIceCandidate(c)));
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('all stored candidates added');
      candidates.length = 0;
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
  else if (json.type === 'ice') {
    if (remoteDescriptionSet) {
      pc.addIceCandidate(json.ice)
      .then(() => console.log(`adding remote ice candidate: ${json.ice.candidate}`))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
    else {
      candidates.push(json.ice);
      console.log(`storing remote ice candidate: ${json.ice.candidate}`);
    }
  }
}
```